# How to parse webm's simpleblock? and get the frame data

Tags: actionscript-3, flv, webm, video-codecs

I want to parse webm file and convert to flv format.
I can get the simple block array, and some information. like this...

```
//d is simple block data
var track_number:uint = d.readByte() & 0xF;
var time_code:uint = d.readShort(); //
var flags:uint = d.readUnsignedByte();
var frame_type:uint = flags >> 7;
var lacing:uint = flags >> 1 & 0x3;
```

how can I get the frame data? and webm have not pps & sps, what can I do for this?

Comment: Hi, there is no webM decoder in AS3. But the webM contains VP8 or VP9 video codec frames. Since webP is really **just a VP8 codec keyframe** (i-frame), maybe you can look at this and try something with it: **[AS3 webP Decoder](https://github.com/soywiz/as3libwebp)**. Good luck.

Comment: PS: As you can see it is C code ported to Flash. If you want to try porting some other decoder's C/C++ code you could try **[Crossbridge](https://github.com/crossbridge-community)**. The **[Chromium VP8 source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/libvpx/+/master/vp8)** looks good to port from C. Finally If instead you prefer code from a **[JavaScript decoder](https://github.com/dominikhlbg/vp8-webm-javascript-decoder/)**.